# Same calendar on iOS and macOS, different alarms?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, calendar, ical

macOS Catalina, iOS 14.8.1

I've been annoyed for ages by getting alarms for events, when I can check them on my mac (where I do 99% of my calendar management) and the alarms are either non-existent, or different (set to "at event time" yet I'm getting an alarm 1 hour ahead of time, etc.)

Just now I finally realized what might be happening and was shocked to discover I was right.  My iOS calendar has completely different alarm settings, for the same events!

I have my default alarm set to 1 hour ahead of time.  I can create an event either on my mac or phone and as long as that's what I want, all is well with the world.  However, if I go into either platform and change the alarm schedule at all - they are no longer in sync.  They ARE the same event, if I move it on one platform it moves on the other, etc.  But the alarms will only change for the platform I'm making the change on.  The other platform will never under any circumstances catch the change.  I've got weekly repeating events that go back years and have been getting erroneous alarms all this time.

On the mac, these calendars are all in iCloud.  None of them are On This Mac or "Other".  Why does this happen, and how can I keep my alarms synchronized between the platforms?

Comment: Not use iCloud as the authoritative storage for the calendars.  It's never been reliable.  Gave up on it years ago, myself.

Comment: Wow that's disheartening!  Do you use something else to keep your calendars synched?  I definitely need to be able to just use either one at any time, I often create calendar events from my phone using Siri, but do major scheduling stuff on the mac.

Comment: Been a Fastmail subscriber for years.  Their CardDAV/CalDAV services follow standards and just work.  Not a commercial, just find somewhere other than iCloud to be authoritative.

Comment: Sigh... I appreciate knowing there is an alternative, but it's gonna really chap my hide to pay $3/month to fix standard built-in functionality.  Still good to know if I get desperate enough... lol

Comment: I have no brand loyalty, I use what works and I'm willing to pay for that.  iCloud has never worked reliably, so I don't use it.